# Div auto height not working

Tags: css, html

Visit (small browser width) [website](http://jainvidhya.co.in) ==> Roll Number ==> type `jit`, there will be scrollbar at that div. (Done)

Now visit (small browser width) [website](http://jainvidhya.co.in) ==> Audio Tutorials ==> click part1, the div height will increase. (Good)

My question is why the `Roll Number` div does not increase the height?

Code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    .card.h-50 {
        height: auto !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Paulie_D agreed, but how can I write a demo having PHP & MySQL in it...?

Comment: You don't, you use **just enough** output HMTL/CSS etc. to demo the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `search-box` div has a fixed height and your `result` div has `position: absolute;` which prevents your `card` div to grow.

Absolutely positioned elements are not counted as part of document flow, so their width and height won't affect the dimensions of their parents.

Simply change the `position: absolute;` to `position:relative;` will fix your problem.

[image: The problematic div.]